# can we run our own WNDPROC() from injected dll and control the running exe?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to run a program which can inject a dll into a running exe and from that dll i want to run a function same as WndProc() to get control of running exe.Basically i want to run GetMessage() of the running exe.

here is my dll injection code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<Windows.h>

void main()
{
  DWORD procId;
  HWND runningWndHandle,dllWnd;
  HANDLE hProcess=NULL;
  char *myDll=new char[200];
  myDll="C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\C# learning\\myDll\\Debug\\myDll.dll";

  runningWndHandle=FindWindow(NULL,"Form1");
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(runningWndHandle,&procId);
  //open process with all access
  hProcess=OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,procId);
  //allocate some space or memory for dll path 
  LPVOID DllVirtLoc=VirtualAllocEx(hProcess,0,strlen(myDll),(DWORD)0x1000,(DWORD)0x04);
  //write dll path to newly allocated space
  WriteProcessMemory(hProcess,DllVirtLoc,myDll,strlen(myDll),NULL);
  //call Load library  with our dllpath as arg from dummy space
  CreateRemoteThread(hProcess,NULL,NULL,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"),(LPCSTR)"LoadLibraryA"),(LPVOID)DllVirtLoc,NULL,NULL);
  //test connection to Dll
  while((dllWnd=FindWindowEx(NULL,NULL,"HOOK from HOME","FIND ME"))==0)
      Sleep(250);
  PostMessageA(dllWnd,0x1111,0,0);
  //create a thread for return messages
  system("PAUSE");
  return ; 

  }

 this code works properly but the dll is creating some problems.
 this is my dll code



// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include <Windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc ( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM ) ;
HINSTANCE hInst ;
void func(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow, char* pTitle)
{
    char classname[ ] = "MyWindowClass" ;
        HWND hWnd ;
        WNDCLASSEX wcex ;
        wcex.cbSize = sizeof ( WNDCLASSEX ) ;
        wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
        wcex.lpfnWndProc = ( WNDPROC ) WndProc ;
        wcex.cbClsExtra = 0 ;
        wcex.cbWndExtra = 0 ;
        wcex.hInstance = hInstance ;
        wcex.hIcon = NULL ;
        wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor ( NULL, IDC_ARROW ) ;
        wcex.hbrBackground = ( HBRUSH )( COLOR_WINDOW + 1 ) ;
        wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL ;
        wcex.lpszClassName =(LPCWSTR)classname ;
        wcex.hIconSm = NULL ;
        if ( !RegisterClassEx ( &wcex ) )
        return;
        hInst = hInstance ; // Store instance handle in our global variable
        hWnd = CreateWindow ((LPCWSTR) classname, (LPCWSTR)pTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL,
        NULL, hInstance, NULL ) ;
        if ( !hWnd )
            return ;
        ShowWindow ( hWnd, nCmdShow ) ;
        UpdateWindow ( hWnd ) ;



        MSG msg;
        while(GetMessage(&msg,0,0,0))
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

        return ;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc ( HWND hWnd, UINT message,WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
switch ( message )
{
        case WM_DESTROY :
           MessageBox(0,L"I WONT LET YOU CLOSE",L"MESSAGE",0);;
        break ;
        default :
        return DefWindowProc ( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam ) ;
}
return 0 ;
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    if(ul_reason_for_call==DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
     //MessageBox(0,L"HELLo FROM INJECTED CODE",L"MESSAGE ",0);
      func((HINSTANCE)hModule,0,"MY WINDOW");
    }
}
```

i want to run the function "func()" and from there want to execute the wndproc() to GetMessages of running exe.Now the PROBLEM is that CreateWindow() is returning an NULL value,and more over it is not going into the WndProc() and it makes the running exe inaccessible(HANG).
Is there any way by which i can run the WNDPROC() and get the messages from running window??

Comment: it is 200 by mistake it became 20. this program creates a space for dll but i am just not able to run WndProc() .

Comment: You cannot create a window in DllMain and you never use GetLastError to find out why CreateWindow failed! Your terminology is also hard to understand.

Comment: Anders- I tried using GetLastError() but for printing that error code i required a MessageBox in dllmain. Which takes an LPCWSTR  as a parameter. When i tried converting that DWORD returned from GetLastError() to LPCWSTR it prints some chinese characters.

Comment: WHAt is the alternative?if i cant create a window there

Comment: If you are not even able to properly convert a number to a wide string then you should not be attempting to inject yourself into another process. Learn the basics first.

Comment: That i can take care of just answer why we cannot create a window.. and if there is way to run that function how can we

Comment: Thanks i will look into it

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a window in DllMain, you will risk a deadlock on the loader lock. [Some reasons not to do anything scary in your DllMain](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040127-00/?p=40873).

You should call `GetLastError` right after `CreateWindow` fails to find out why. It looks like you are compiling the .DLL with UNICODE defined but you are using narrow strings everywhere and casting to LPCWSTR, don't do that! There should be very few casts in your code. Only cast the return value of `GetProcAddress` in your case. The strings should be prefixed with `L` or compile everything as ANSI.

There should be plenty of examples of dll injection on Codeprojects and other sites that show how to call a function outside DllMain. The sloppy way is to just use `GetExitCodeThread` on the first thread after `WaitForSingleObject` and then create another remote thread because you now have the information needed to calculate the address of `func` in the remote process (local GetProcAddress - local LoadLibrary + remote LoadLibrary). [This article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces) should get you started.

After injection you can [subclass the window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).